# How to split a file into contiguous non-empty-line blocks in Scala?

Tags: scala, parsing

E.g. we've got a file of the following contents:

```
aaa
  bbb
ccc

dd dd
eee
fff

gg
hhhhh
```

The task is to parse this file into an ordered/numbered collection (a map, an array or whatever) that will contain the three contiguous blocks as collections of strings.

Doing this an algorithmic Java-flavoured way seems fairly obvious but It'd be great if somebody could suggest a functional Scala-idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use Stream.span:

```
scala> def chunks(s: Stream[String]): Stream[Seq[String]] = {
     | val (h, t) = s.span(_.nonEmpty)
     | h.toSeq #:: chunks(t.tail) }
chunks: (s: Stream[String])Stream[Seq[String]]
```

With some finesse:

```
scala> def chunks(s: Stream[String]): Stream[Stream[String]] = {
     | val (h, t) = s.span(_.nonEmpty)
     | if (h.isEmpty) Stream.empty else h #:: chunks(t drop 1) }
chunks: (s: Stream[String])Stream[Stream[String]]

scala> val cs = chunks(lines.lines.toStream).iterator
cs: Iterator[Stream[String]] = non-empty iterator

scala> cs.next.toList
res0: List[String] = List(aaa, "  bbb", ccc)

scala> cs.next.toList
res1: List[String] = List(dd dd, eee, fff)

scala> cs.next.toList
res2: List[String] = List(gg, hhhhh)

scala> cs.hasNext
res3: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting by arbitrary delimiter (`|`) and grouping to separate blocks:

```
val blocks: List[List[String]] = Source
  .fromFile("<path-to-file>").getLines()
  .mkString("|")
  .split("\\|{2,}").toList
  .map(_.split("\\|").toList)
```

This gives you a

```
List(List(aaa,   bbb, ccc), List(dd dd, eee, fff), List(gg, hhhhh))
```

Comment: That `mkString` will lead to a lot of unwanted problems on reasonably large files. And if you want to read all the file in memory then you don't need to do `mkString` at all you can just divide list using `isEmpty` check on each element. Although you are having the result in memory so its not going to matter anyway. But if we wanted to stream those contiguous blocks we should avoid reading all that into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use split to transform it:

```
def contigSplit(s : String) : Array[Array[String]] = s.split("\n\n").map(_.split("\n"))
```

This works because a contiguous block terminates with two line breaks.

**REPL Usage:**

```
scala> val s = """
     | aaa
     |   bbb
     | ccc
     | 
     | dd dd
     | eee
     | fff
     | 
     | gg
     | hhhhh
     | """

scala> s.split("\n\n").map(_.split("\n"))
res7: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array("", aaa, "  bbb", ccc), Array(dd dd, eee, fff), Array(gg, hhhhh))
```

**Alternative:**

If the blanks lines could contain other whitespace, a regex split can be used:

```
def contigSplitRegEx(s : String) : Array[Array[String]] = "\n\\s*\n".r.split(s).map(_.split("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getListOfContguousLists(iterator: Iterator[String]): List[List[String]] = {
  val (listOfContiguousList, lastList) = iterator
    .foldLeft((List.empty[List[String]], List.empty[String]))({
      case ((listOfLists, list), line) => (line.isEmpty, list.isEmpty) match {
        case (true, true) => (listOfLists, list)
        case (true, false) => (listOfLists :+ list, List.empty[String])
        case (false, _) => (listOfLists, list :+ line)
      }
    })
  lastList.isEmpty match {
    case true => listOfContiguousList
    case false => listOfContiguousList :+ lastList
  }
}

val list = getListOfContiguousLists(scala.io.Source.fromFile("").getLines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a map of numbered buckets and take line number % 3 to decide with bucket to put the line

```
Source.fromFile("some_file").getLines().toList.filterNot(_.isEmpty)
      .zipWithIndex
      .foldLeft(Map(0 -> List.empty[String], 1 -> List.empty[String], 2 -> List.empty[String])) { (result, current) =>
        result.updated(current._2 % 3, result(current._2 % 3) ++ List(current._1))
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not purely functional, but is fairly neat as an iterator

```
def groupBlanksIterator(xs:Iterator[String]) =
 new Iterator[List[String]]
  { def hasNext = xs.hasNext; def next = xs.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).toList}

groupBlanksIterator(scala.io.Source.fromFile("whatever").getLines)
```